What is the difference between these HOC components

Passing children and returning children with additional logic

const WithLoadingState =(props)=> {
  // Handle display the spinner, error message etc

if(!props.error) return props.children
}


Actual HOC component

const withLoadingState =(Component) => (props)=> {
   // Additional logics here, display spinner, error message etc.

if(!props.error) return <Component {...props} />
}

For the above 2 components, I think they do achieve the same results. The first one, I am not sure what it's called. But, that first component seems way simpler and cleaner to implement.
Second component is what they call HOC and is more complicated and harder to use. So, I was wondering, why people use HOC component whereas the First Component can bascially achieve the same thing.
The obstacle I came across with HOC is, we have to call it outside of the React Component. We can call inside the React Component itself. But, IMO, it's ugly.
Usage

Component One (1)

const MyData =()=> 
<WithLoadingState>
   <MyList />
</WithLoadingState>


HOC Component

const MyData =()=> withLoadingState(MyList)

Or
const MyListWithLoadingState = withLoadingState(MyList)

const MyData =()=> <MyListWithLoadingState />

What are the differences and what benefits does HOC component offer?

You can't pass any props to children with the first one
